# docker-compose won't use my named volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

So I'm fairly new to docker. I have an issue with attaching my named volumes to services in my swarm.

Here is my docker-compose.yml...

```
version: '3'
services:
  ned:
    image: keli
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - craig
      - paul
  craig:
    image: cb
    volumes:
      - cbKeli:/opt/couchbase/var
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
  paul:
    image: pg
    volumes:
      - pgKeli:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  pgKeli:
  cbKeli:
```

However, after a `docker-compose up` I end up with new volumes.

```
$ docker volume ls | grep -i keli
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               cbKeli
local               kelidocker_cbKeli
local               kelidocker_pgKeli
local               pgKeli
```

What's up with that?  How can I get my new swarm to use an existing named volume?

Comment: I might add that I had previously created the `cbKeli` and `pgKeli` volumes with a `docker volume create <bla>`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: so, what you want is, all the `VOLUME NAME` to be just `cbKeli` and `pgKeli` like you set in your `volumes:`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell compose that this is an externally created volume. To do that, you use the external key on the volume definition like this:

```
volumes:
  cbKeli:
    external: true
  pgKeli:
    external: true
```

See the following documentation for further information on external volumes: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1 (external is used for networks and config as well)